# Azure Pipelines - authenticate git in powershell

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In my release pipeline I have a powershell task, where I want to to invoke some custom git commands like `git fetch`

I'm getting

> fatal: Cannot prompt because terminal prompts have been disabled.

> fatal: could not read Password for 'https://myproject@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled

How do I authenticate the agent?

I could you the same authentication as Agent in "Download Artifacts" task.

[image]

Comment: it does have permissions, because it can download artifacts, which is the same git repository. However I need to do the same in another directory in powershell. Question is, how do I authenticate as Project Collection Build Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the agent token as the authentication of git command in your release pipeline, you can do like as below:

1. Enable the "**Allow scripts to access the OAuth token**" option on the job.
   [image]
2. Then, on the PowerShell task, you can use the environment variable "**`$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN`**" in the git command lines as the authentication.

For example:

```
git clone https://:$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProj/_git/MyRepo
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is failing because the git command line is waiting for entering credentials.

But an ADO pipeline already has a valid token in a pre-defined env variable `System.AccessToken`

Add `-c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"` (in `cmd` syntax) at the beginning of your git command line (just before the git verb `pull`)

The syntax could be a little different in powershell.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken for predefined variables documentation and the exact transformation syntax.
In powershell it should be something like `$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN`

Comment: I had to add `-c` before verb, not after, e.g `git -c .... fetch`

Comment: @Liero And it worked after doing that? If yes, please accept the answer and I will update the answer to be right....

Comment: Yep, but another answer already accepted, I can accept only one, but you got upvote. Also, I had to enable "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token" option on the job.

Comment: @Liero Fair. I've not seen that you already accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

### Yaml pipelines

Please check out this page on Microsoft Learn about using custom git commands in pipelines:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

The trick from keeping *signed-in* is to use persistCredentials

```yaml
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
```

This is usely done in the build phase when one or more repos are checked out.

In your case it's in the deployment phase
Not sure if it will work in deployment as well...

Just out of curiosity...
What is functionally in the repo?
And why are you doing this in the deployment phase?

### Classic Release pipelines

There is also an alternative, you can use multiple artifacts in your classic release pipelines. Maybe that will help you?
[image: two artifact]

The pipeline will do the hard work for you then:
[image: run screenshot]

Comment: Not sure if there's the option to `persistCredential ` in a classic release pipeline.
The repo doesn't contain code, but email/pdf templates. Those templates must deployable independently of the app

Comment: Sorry, missed the part of classic release pipeline. Will update my answer

Comment: @Liero May I suggest an (better?) alternative, see my edit of just now!

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of it, but that's not exactly what I want. I need to pull specific version in a deployment directory, not in a build agent working directory. For some reasons, there is a cloned git repo in the deployment directory, so I can't just copy artifacts there

Comment: ok no worries, the OAuth + headers is also a good option

Answer (score 0):

As **Bright Ran-MSFT** said you can use `git clone https://:$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProj/_git/MyRepoYou`
Need to Disable [Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elZF6.png) setting in project pipeline for cloning in classic Pipeline